# Does attacking from your echo knight while hidden give you advantage/Reveal your position?

Tags: attack, rogue, fighter, stealth, advantage-and-disadvantage

The title says it all.

If I'm a rogue/fighter multiclass, and I attack with my echo knight while hidden, does the attack have advantage?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Exchange! We cover many different tabletop systems here, and any answer is going to depend on which one you're using. You'll need to update your question with a system tag before this is answerable.

Comment: @rykara I've gone ahead and rolled back your edit--it's not at all clear to me where you're getting OP's statement/confirmation that it's dnd-5e they're playing. If there's something I've missed please go ahead and edit the tag in, and include a note in the edit summary as to how you know that's the right tag.Thanks.